# What is the best practice to set initial state in reactjs constructor redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using reactjs and redux for my application. This is a piece of code from my Dashboard component. just wonder if assigning state with hard coded value in my constructor is considered bad practice.

```
export class Dashboard extends React.Component{

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state={
            dashboardRequest : {
                groupingFilter  : 0, paginationInfo :{ currentPage : 1, pageSize : 5} ,  sortInfo : {sortBy  : 'grossNotional', ascending : true}
            }
        };
        autoBind(this);
    }

    onChange(current){
        const dashboardRequest = this.state.dashboardRequest;
        dashboardRequest.paginationInfo.currentPage = current;
        this.setState({dashboardRequest : dashboardRequest});
        this.props.actions.fetchDashboard(this.state.dashboardRequest);
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        dashboard: state.dashboard,
        isLoading : state.dashboard.isLoading,
        isOverflow : state.dashboard.isOverflow,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(AppActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Dashboard);

export const dashboardReducer = (previousState = { }, action) => {
    let {type, ...actionData} = action;
    switch (type) {
        case 'LOAD_DASHBOARD_DATA':
            return {...previousState, ...actionData};
        case 'ADD_DASHBOARD_DATA':
            return {...previousState, ...actionData};
        default:
            return previousState;
    }
};
```

Comment: If you're using Redux, you likely won't need state in your component much or at all.  Create a state.js file and set up your initial state tree there.

Comment: Its fine to use state if you want to; pagination is a classic example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Local state is fine**. Even though if you are using Redux. You don't need to stop using `setState()` *just because* you're using Redux.

Redux is just a state management library in which you describe your **application state** as plain **objects** and **arrays**, also known as your **store**.

Before rendering your components, it's important to **decide** your state, to **model** your store. To help you decide if some state must be in the store (together with your **whole** application state), there are some questions you may ask:

- Do other components rely on that state?
- Do you need to persist (*and/or* trace) that state?

But only that doesn't answer your question (where to set initial state).
If you decided to go with **local state**, I think your code is fine the way it is. If it needs to make part of your **store**, you need to set it as initial/default state for it.

You can do it in the [`createStore()`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html) function, passing the `preloadedState` argument. But if your default state is fixed (*hardcoded*), maybe you can put it in the `initialState` for `dasboardReducer`! Here's an example:

```
const initialState = {
    groupingFilter: 0,
    paginationInfo: { currentPage: 1, pageSize: 5 },
    sortInfo: ... 
};

function dashboardReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    // ...
}
```

**What I would do in your case?** I would keep all my `dashboardRequest` info in the store, managed by Redux. It's no a longer local state, I need to send it to the server, dispatching a side-effect action.

So, I would keep the definition of my default `dashboardRequest` info as my reducer's `initialState`, as in the example.

I really hope it helped you. Here are the readings I used for reference:

- [You Might Not Need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367), by Dan Abramov;
- [setState() Gate](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/setstate-gate-abc10a9b2d82), by Eric Elliott.

Real World examples are also welcome! Take a deep look at it: [Redux Real World Example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world).

Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much. This is really informative. I have this dashboardRequest which is sent to server-side in order to get response data but I am not populating dashboardRequest on server side. In this case, Am I ok with setState? Thanks again for your post. This clears a lot of things in my head.

Comment: Oh, sorry to keep you waiting... Even though you are not populating `dashboardRequest` data in server side, would be ok if you decide to save it in your store. Even so, if `dashboardRequest` data as **local state** doesn't bother you, and it will be easy to mantain, I think you're ok. If one day you want to persist that state (e.g., saving to localStorage), you can consider adding it to the store.

Comment: Also, in your example, the only thing that you really use in the `onChange` method is the `currentPage` property. You can keep a local state just for that property, and put the rest in another place (maybe as default options in your `fetchDashboard` function). If it was only for the sake of the example, ignore this comment, hahaha.